# Go to a UISegmentedControl index in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've connected a UISegmentedControl outlet. In my viewDidLoad() I check some stuff out to determine if I need to jump to the third index of the UISegmentedControl but I had no luck.

I made this:

```
self.mainSelector.isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex(2)
```

Of course it did't work. What should I do to jump automatically to the third segment?

Comment: Is `selectedSegmentIndex = 2` what your looking for? It sets the third segmented to the selected state.

Comment: I think it worked. I did mainSelector.selectedSegmentIndex = 2, and it changes the tab but it doesn't load its content. Only change the selected tab but it doesn't go to that view.

Comment: Setting the selected segment programatically doesn't fire the segment's actions.

Comment: So what should I do? I've instantiated the view controller I want to show but it's shown full screen. This viewController is a UIContentView so I need to be presented that way.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do, and what is a `UIContentView`?

Comment: UIContainerView excuse me!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104117/discussion-between-paulvs-and-a-sola).

Answer (score 1):

The selected segment in a UISegmentedControl is determined by its [`selectedSegmentIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex).

Comment: I've made 

let vc : AnyObject! = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("random")
                self.showViewController(vc as! UIViewController, sender: vc)

 but it shows the view controller not inside UISegmentControl but full screen just like a normal view

Comment: That isn't what you asked. If you have a different question, ask a different question.